# ways to create customized theme (hard coded - no pagebuilder)

Tags: theme-development, child-theme

I'm a front-end developer, I have question hope u guys can help me, what do you think is the best practice to create a customized theme? I have this project and I'm contemplating which method to use. There's this existing exotic blogging web design that I need to convert to an actual wordpress theme

**method #1**
My solution to this is to use a blank theme, any theme mentioned on this blog/article https://www.webfx.com/blog/web-design/blank-wordpress-themes/  and then do the magic, write `CSS`, `HTML`, `PHP` and `JS` on my own. I'm considering using this theme https://github.com/html5blank/html5blank but
**my concern** is if the `Wordpress` / `PHP` version changes, will those blank themes will go down? will it negatively affect the site?

**method #2**
one suggested to me that we should use a lightweight theme like `generatepress` / `genesis` / `kadence theme` and overwrite it all using `child-theme`.

So basically in **method #2** I'll overwrite the existing `single-page`, `single-post` and any other layouts of the selected theme using `child-theme` using `CSS`, `JS`, `HTML`, and `PHP`. In my own opinion it makes no sense to do a fully customized WordPress theme using those kind of theme if we are going to overwrite it all using `child-theme`, might as well start from scratch or use blank theme.

So what do you guys think? Am I missing something? does **method #2** make sense? or **method #1** is the perfect approach for this? I just want to know all the possibilities, weigh the **pros / cons** before I proceed to the development phase.

Comment: Both methods will work, so it's a matter of personal preference.  For me, one of the things I find most frustrating is when I have to work against another developers assumptions, so I always look for a starting point that's as 'empty' of design as possible.  About once a year I go to https://underscores.me (which is the framework that Automattic uses for their themes), output a new empty theme and then modify it to strip it down even further. For the rest of the year, I use that stripped down version  of underscores as my starting point for all themes.

Comment: thanks @TonyDjukic this is very insightful.